# copy contents of a folder from one location to another using ruby

Tags: ruby, copy, directory

I wrote this code to copy files from one location to another, but I want to copy the contents of the entire folder to a target location.

How do I do this? I tried file.copy dir, but it doesn't work.

```
require 'ftools'
fname = gets.chomp

if fname == "android" then
  File.copy "/Volumes/TempData/Collects/Sasi/android/grade.rb","/Volumes/Data"
elsif fname == "ios" then
  File.copy"/Volumes/Sasi/ios/grade.rb","/Volumes/TempData/Sasi/KugaViewr/grade.rb"
else 
  puts "do nothing"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[`FileUtils#copy_entry`](http://yard.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/FileUtils.html#copy_entry-class_method) will be the good choice for this thing.

> Copies a file system entry src to dest. If src is a directory, this method copies its contents recursively. This method preserves file types, c.f. symlink, directory... (FIFO, device files and etc. are not supported yet)

Answer (score 0):

From the pickaxe (1.8), p 681:

> The FileUtils library is now recommended over ftools.

If you have to use ftools for some reason, see [ftools solution](http://books.google.com/books?id=ows9jTsyaaEC&pg=PA409&lpg=PA409&dq=ruby%20ftools%20recursive%20copy&source=bl&ots=imQDGVoiHl&sig=dtmXtcCgXfYy2-Lh0DkAvc7cBTQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=u6rSUcSxK-msiALq1IDICg&ved=0CEwQ6AEwBjgK#v=onepage&q=ruby%20ftools%20recursive%20copy&f=false).